# error in calling function with int? as input

Tags: c#

I have a function like that :

```
 public int? calculateContractPrice(int? comid)
    {
        int? sum = 0;
        var q = from i in dbconnect.tblMaterialGroups
                where i.tenderId == _tenderId
                select i.id;
        foreach (int i in q )
        {
            var q2 = from g in dbconnect.tblMaterialTenderAnnouncePrices
                     where g.MaterialGroupId == i && g.companyId == comid
                     select g;
            sum = q2.First().amount*q2.First().price + q2.First().amount*q2.First().PriceForElse + sum;


        }
        return sum+(from i in dbconnect.tblContracts where i.tender==_tenderId select i.tax).First();
    }
```

So when i call this function :

```
    int coid = Convert.ToInt32(gvcompanyInTender.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString());

    objco.Tax =int.Parse((objco.calculateContractPrice(coid)) * (6 / 100));
```

I got this error:
I think the problem is because of the int? that i defined,but i don't know how can i resolve that.

```
   Error    19  The best overloaded method match for 'int.Parse(string)' has some invalid arguments
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result of `(objco.calculateContractPrice(coid)) * (6 / 100)` is an `int?` value, not `string`, so you can't call `int.Parse` on it, and there would be no reason to.

Another problem is that the result of that calculation will be `0` if the result of `calculateContractPrice` is non-null, because `6 / 100` is equal to `0` under integer division.

Ideally, you should be checking whether the value is null before using it, since it is an `int?`:

```
int? contrPrice = objco.calculateContractPrice(coid);
if(contrPrice == null)
{
   // error handling
}
else
{
    objco.Tax = (int)(contrPrice * (6D / 100));
}
```

Comment: objco.tax is an attribute of class and it is integer

Comment: Ok, but you don't need `int.Parse` to convert an `int` to an `int`. It's already an `int`.

Answer (score 0):

the `int.Parse` accept `string` as argument, you need to change :

```
objco.Tax =int.Parse((objco.calculateContractPrice(coid)) * (6 / 100));
```

to:

```
objco.Tax =int.Parse(((objco.calculateContractPrice(coid)) * (6 / 100)).ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

The error comes down to this expression

```
(objco.calculateContractPrice(coid)) * (6 / 100)
```

The type of this operation is `int?` not `String`.  The `int.Parse` method expects a `String` and hence errors when you give it an `int?`.

To convert an `int?` to a `int` value you need to either use `Value` or pick an appropriate default for the case that it is `null`.  The `Value` property will throw when the value is `null` so I recommend using `??` and picking an appropriate default

```
objco.Tax = ((objco.calculateContractPrice(coid)) * (6 / 100)).Value;
// Or 
objco.Tax = ((objco.calculateContractPrice(coid)) * (6 / 100)) ?? 0;
```